# Where does this Emacs Lisp hook function get its argument from?

Tags: emacs, hook, org-mode, local-variables

I'm just learning emacs and came across a [configuration](https://github.com/angrybacon/dotemacs) that demonstrates quite a bit of the functionality I want in my own configuration. It uses [init.el](https://github.com/angrybacon/dotemacs/blob/master/init.el) as an entry point to an org file that handles the bulk of the configuration with extensive documentation. I am confused by the following function:

```
(put 'after-save-hook 'safe-local-variable
       (lambda (value) (equal value '(org-babel-tangle t))))
```

What I think I understand is that this puts the value of the lambda expression into the property list of `after-save-hook` under the property name `safe-local-variable`, and that a value is safe if, when passed to the `safe-local-variable-p` function it returns a non-nil value. This lambda then appears to do an equality comparison between `value` and the list `(org-babel-tangle t)`, so presumably this means that `value` is safe only when it's equal to the list `(org-babel-tangle t)`?

What I am having trouble understanding is twofold. First, where is the lambda getting `value` from? Second, what is this all actually doing? Neither the documentation I could find on `after-save-hook` nor `org-babel-tangle` clarified this for me. The author's comments say "Mark safe variables early so that tangling won't break," but I still don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that the file `DESKTOP.org` starts with this line:

```
# -*- after-save-hook: (org-babel-tangle t); -*-
```

That is, when you open that file in Emacs, the local value of `after-save-hook` becomes `(org-babel-tangle t)`.  So whenever you save that file, it's going to call the function `org-babel-tangle` without any arguments, in order to generate a few shell scripts, e.g. `scripts/screenshot.region.sh`.  The value `t` in a hook variable means that after calling all the functions in the *local* value of the hook variable, `run-hooks` is going to look at the *global* value of `after-save-hook` and call any functions listed there as well.

Obviously, allowing any file to specify arbitrary Lisp code to be run would be a security hole equaled only by Microsoft Word macros, so by default file-local settings for risky variables are ignored.  Since we know this particular value is safe,<sup>*</sup> we use the `safe-local-variable` trick you're asking about.  As per the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Local-Variables.html):

> You can specify safe values for a variable with a
> ‘safe-local-variable’ property.  The property has to be a function of
> one argument; any value is safe if the function returns non-‘nil’ given
> that value.

So that's what we have here:

```
(lambda (value) (equal value '(org-babel-tangle t)))
```

It is a function that takes one argument, and checks that the argument is equal to the specific value we want to allow.  `safe-local-variable-p` is going to call this function on the specified file-local value, and only allow it if the function returns non-nil.  Thus, `value` is going to be the value that is about to be assigned to `after-save-hook`.  We can see that in action in `M-x ielm`:

```
*** Welcome to IELM ***  Type (describe-mode) for help.
ELISP> (setq my-function (lambda (value) (equal value '(org-babel-tangle t))))
(lambda
  (value)
  (equal value
         '(org-babel-tangle t)))

ELISP> (funcall my-function '(org-babel-tangle t))
t
ELISP> (funcall my-function 'something-else)
nil
```

---

<sup>*</sup> Is this safe, though?... If an attacker can get you to download a specially crafted file and run `org-babel-tangle` on it, they can overwrite arbitrary files in the file system using the privileges of your user.  It's not what's happening in this case, just something to be aware of.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed reply. I just want to attempt to summarize to verify my own understanding: the purpose of the code is to mark the code which we want to run as an after-save-hook as safe, effectively granting it permission to run, as by default this code would be prevented from running for security purposes. Is that about right?

Answer (score 2):

The anonymous function with argument `value` gets its arg from the value of `after-save-hook`.

`after-save-hook` is a variable. Its value is a list of hooks.

This code puts the anonymous function as the `safe-local-variable` property value of symbol `after-save-hook`, so that when `after-save-hook` is processed as to see if it is a safe local variable, that function is called. The function is called on the current value of the variable, `after-save-hook`.

See the Elisp manual, node [File Local Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Local-Variables.html).

Comment: So, is it the end result of this specific lambda that only a hook equal to `org-babel-tangle` is considered safe? Also, what is the point of the `t` after `org-babel-tangle` in the quote?

Comment: When a hook has a buffer-local value (which will be a list), if one of the list items is `t` then the *global* value of the hook will be used as well as the buffer-local value.  Without a `t` value, *only* the functions in the buffer-local list would be called.